# Why does environment variable BUILD_NUMBER interfere with .NET references during build?

Tags: .net, jenkins, msbuild

I call MSBuild from the command line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /t:clean,build /p:configuration="Release" /p:platform="Any CPU" MySolution.sln
```

The solution contains several projects and nuget package references. E.g. Project1 references log4net via nuget. Project2 references Project1.

References are configured as copy-local, and as a result I get the log4net DLL in Project1's bin folder as well as in Project2's bin folder.

However, when I trigger the build from Jenkins I always miss the secondary references, i.e. in Project2's bin folder I find Project1's DLL but not log4net -- although log4net is present in Project1's bin folder.

I was able to track the reason down to the existence of the environment variable BUILD_NUMBER (e.g. 10) which is automatically set by Jenkins. I tested in a console window: If it is there then the problem appears as described. If it is not there all DLLs are where I expect them.

How can I proceed on this? Any suggestions are welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Reinhard

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the disturbance, I caused the problem by myself, precisely like that:

I created a post-build event hook for Project1 that did some binary protection only when the evironment variable BUILD_NUMBER was set. Once that was done MSBuild failed in the ResolveAssemblyReferences step for Project1 because it was not able to discover the references in the protected assembly.

Lesson learned ;)